# Inner join and right outer join values

Tags: sql

Can somebody help in understanding what would be the result of the 2 tables when inner join and right outer join is applied

| ID | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |

| ID | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |
| 1 | E |
| 1 | F |

Comment: Both will produce 9 rows. Rest you can try this by yourself. This is very simple practice. You must try first before posting a question here.

Comment: Which columns are you joining on?

Comment: @nofinator using the column id

Comment: Thanks. Then I think what Ankit said is correct. Try using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to give it a quick try yourself.